# Remove Text Appearing before the Program Output

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Background:** I'm running JDK 16 on WSL2 and using VScode on windows. I have java essential Java Vscode extensions installed.

**The problem is**, whenever I run the java code, I get this annoying text that appears just before the actual output of the program.
[image]

Someone please tell me **how to remove this text**. I would prefer my output to look clean and show only the program output. Much thanks.

Comment: What happens if you just click the output tab?

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke, nothing is shown in the output tab. Its blank.

Comment: That's unfortunate, it seemed like a rather obvious place to have your output without the actual command being echoed. Can't help you with this then, I'm afraid I've never used VS Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such settings provided by java extension to achieve your goals, but we have some workaround to get pure result:

**Without extra extension:**

1. Create [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configure) and set `"console": "internalConsole"`,. Then **Run without Debugging**, the result will be shown in **Debug Console** and no execution scripts:
   [image]
2. In `launch.json`, set `"console": "externalTerminal"`,. Then **Run without Debugging**, the result will be shown in **external Terminal** and no execution scripts:
   [image]

**Install extra extension** [Code Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68447011/remove-text-appearing-before-the-program-output):

Add the following configurations in Settings.json:

```
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false
```

Clicking the triangle button and choose **Run Code**, the result is shown in **OUTPUT** and no execution scripts:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: @AtoKoomson. Happy Coding:)